# Calling another class's init causes Linker error (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, initialization, linker-errors

I'm using a class called AudioFile in another class called MyManager. Trying to use other methods from AudioFile gives no errors and will build out. But if I try to use use AudioFile's init, I get a linker error when I try to build.
Note: I still get the error even if I call init from somewhere else in MyManager

MyManager.mm

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)AudioFile *audioFile;

-(id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {

    }
    self.audioFile = [[AudioFile alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

AudioFile.m

```
- (id)init
{
    //initializer stuff
    return self;
}
```

error looks like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AudioFile", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in myManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: are you using a precompiled version of AudioFile?

Comment: Don't think so, it's just a .m with a .h